# Teamcity slow; 100% disk usage

Tags: teamcity

On one of my server's teamcity is running all build steps extremely slowly.

Using Teamcity perfmon I traced it to 100% disk usage doing simple tasks like running a nant script with a copy.
[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there was a type of Windows logging switched on on the server. Teamcity does a lot of things, and so the logging of what teamcity was doing was disk heavy. The type of logging was identified by looking at what process was hogging disk usage using Task Manager. I can't remember what it was, but switching off this Windows related logging solved the problem